# How to iterate List<HashMap> in drools file and update the Hash Map objects and return the updated List

Tags: drools

Facing Problem with Iteration of List in drl file. I need to Retrieve each HashMap object and check for 'Issue' key. If value of 'issue' is not empty then need to add a value to 'alert' key.

```
public class ReservationAlerts {

       public enum AlertType {
            RESERVATIONDETAILSRESPONSE
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        private List<HashMap> reservationMap;

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        public List<HashMap> getReservationMap() {
            return reservationMap;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        public void setReservationMap(List<HashMap> reservationMap) {
            this.reservationMap = reservationMap;
        }
        }
```

Main Java Program:

```
DroolsTest.java
public class DroolsTest {
   @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public static final void main(String[] args) {
      try {

         // load up the knowledge base
         KnowledgeBase kbase = readKnowledgeBase();
         StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();

         ReservationAlerts rAlerts = new ReservationAlerts();
         List<HashMap> hashMapList = new ArrayList<>();
         HashMap<String, String> hMap = new HashMap<>();
         hMap.put("rId", "101");
         hMap.put("fName", "ABC");
         hMap.put("lName", "DEF");
         hMap.put("issue", "1qaz");
         hMap.put("alert", "");
         hashMapList.add(hMap);

         HashMap<String, String> hMapI = new HashMap<>();
         hMapI.put("rId", "102");
         hMapI.put("fName", "GHI");
         hMapI.put("lName", "JKL");
         hMapI.put("issue", "");
         hMapI.put("alert", "");
         hashMapList.add(hMapI);
         rAlerts.setReservationMap(hashMapList);

         System.out.println("**********BEFORE************");
         System.out.println(hMap.keySet());
         System.out.println("****************************");
         System.out.println(hMapI.keySet());
         System.out.println("****************************");

         ksession.insert(rAlerts);
         ksession.fireAllRules();
.............
```

Need to update the HashMap and return the updated List from drl file. Can any one Help me plz

```
Drool File being triggered from Java File
    Reservations.drl

    import com.dwh.poc.ReservationAlerts;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Iterator;

    // declare any global variables here
    dialect "java"
    rule "Reservation Alert"
       // Retrieve List from ReservationAlerts
       when
          $rAlerts : ReservationAlerts()
          $alertsMapList : List() from $rAlerts.reservationMap

       then
       // Iterate List and retrieve HashMap object
       for(Iterator it = $alertsMapList.iterator();it.hasNext();) {
          $alertMap : it.next();
       }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `from` in your rule will automatically loop over the list returned by `$rAlerts.reservationMap`. This means that the pattern you need to use in the left hand side of your `from` is `Map` and not `List`. 
Once you have the Map pattern you can add the constraint about the 'issue' key.

Try something like this:

```
rule "Reservation Alert"
when
    $rAlerts : ReservationAlerts()
    $map : Map(this["issue"] != "") from $rAlerts.reservationMap
then
    $map.put("alert", "XXXX");
end
```

Hope it helps,